# How to center text inside of font-awesome circle

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have css/html below and I want to center the text inside of the circle. I can calculate the correct margin if there is only 1 digit, but I would like it to always work, even if there are two or three digits. Anyone have a good solution for this?

```css
.circle-stack {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: 25px;
    left: 5px;
}
  
.fa-circle-thin,
.points-indicator {
    position: absolute;
}
.fa-circle{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #c0cff6;
}

.points-indicator {
  color: #1f0e3e;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 1px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="circle-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <a href="/notifications" title="Unread notifications"><span class="points-indicator">10</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without using font awesome icon also.

The trick is to set the item inside circle-stack class with css

```
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

Here is a [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Netdeamon/8rvdw7qj/1/) of your above code

Preview
[image: image preview]

I changed the order of `span` and `a` tag as the `points-indicator` class was applied to span.
You can use `text-decoration:none` for `a` tag inside span to remove the underline.

Comment: Thanks. There is still a lot of CSS i am far from comfortable with, let alone fluent. Like the transform property. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is any need of font-awesome library. You can do it simply by this:

```css
.circle{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:100px;
  background-color:#000;
}
.circle a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <a href="#">10</a>
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <a href="#">100</a>
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <a href="#">1000</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```css
.circle-stack {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.fa-circle-thin,
.points-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.fa-circle {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #c0cff6;
}

.points-indicator {
  color: #1f0e3e;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="circle-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <a href="/notifications" title="Unread notifications"><span class="points-indicator">10</span></a>
</div>
```